# как реализовать вывод информации из функции в label? tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *



def clicked():
    a = int(input())
    suffix = ("го.....д" if 11 <= a <= 19 or a % 10 == 1 else
                "лет")



window = Tk()
window.title("Счетчик возраста")
window.geometry('400x250')

lbl = Label(window, text="введите число")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)



txt = Entry(window,width=10)
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

btn = Button(window, text='Ок', command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=5, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: имеется функция, нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки, она сработала и вывела результат в label

Comment: `lbl.config(text='...')`

Comment: добавьте в функцию lbl.config(text='результат')